# Download byte array from AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, arrays

I have a byte array in my angular controller and when I click the download button in my view I would like to launch the browser's download/saveAs dialog with 'report.pdf' pre-populated as the filename and PDF as the type. Then just save the file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Just download file , `window.open()` can be used